# Using DISTINCT ON for a column of type timestamp to extract the most recent value for each day

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct-on, datestamp

I have a table named assets:

```
create table assets (
    id            bigint                                 primary key,
    name          varchar(255)                           not null,
    value         double precision                       not null,
    business_time timestamp with time zone,
    insert_time   timestamp with time zone default now() not null
);
```

I am trying to write a query to get the most recent `value` for each day based on `business_time`. This is a sample query that I wrote:

```
select distinct on (business_time::date) business_time::date, value
from home.assets
where name = 'USD_RLS'
order by business_time::date desc
```

But the value for each day is not always the most recent one. I guess it's a bit random which value I get for each day. Any idea how I could fix this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a good way to approach this requirement, but not with DISTINCT ON.

Start by getting the maximum value of the `business_time` timestamp value (including date and time) for each calendar day, thusly.

```
             SELECT MAX(business_time) business_time,
                    business_time::date day
               FROM assets
              WHERE name = 'USD_RLS'
              GROUP BY business_time::date
```

This subquery returns the latest timestamp for each calendar day.

Then use that list of timestamps to get the detail records you need.

```sql
SELECT value, business_time::date day
  FROM assets
 WHERE business_time IN (
                 SELECT MAX(business_time) business_time
                   FROM assets
                  WHERE name = 'USD_RLS'
                  GROUP BY business_time::date )
   AND name = 'USD_RLS'
 ORDER BY business_time::date;
```

It's all about sets. First you find the set of timestamps that are the latest for each calendar day. Then you find the set of rows that have those timestamps.

Comment: Thanks. this works. There is just a slight issue. the latest entry is always at business_time 23:50:00 but this query is always taking the value for business_time 22:50 instead of 23:50. I'm almost sure this is due to timezone. I'm in +1:00 UTC.

Answer (score 1):

What you are facing is truncating the time from the timestamp, thus every row for a date has the same time (00:00:00). You can use a slightly unorthodox, but in this case effective sorting. Sort by the date (ascending or descending - it does not matter) then (the unorthodox part) sort by the full timestamp desc (must be descending). That will give the the latest time for each date.

```
select distinct on (business_time::date) 
       business_time, value
  from assets
 where name = 'USD_RLS'
 order by business_time::date, business_time desc;
```

**NOTE:** Not tested, no data supplied.